# search filter by name in react using input

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have a table of users and I have to filter/search users by the name entered. For example, when typing John, I must list all users named John in the table.

Table code with all users

**ListPatients.js**

```
const ListPatients = ({ pacientes, setPacientes }) => {

  const removePaciente = (idToDelete) => {
    const newTasks = [...pacientes];
    newTasks.splice(idToDelete, 1);
    setPacientes(newTasks);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ display:"flex", alignItems:"center", flexDirection:'column'}}>
      <h1>List</h1>
      <Table style={{ border:'1'}}>
        <thead>
          <tr style={{padding:'0 1rem'}}>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birth date</th>
            <th>CPF</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Addres</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {pacientes.length > 0 ? (
            pacientes.map((paciente, index) => (
              <tr key={paciente.id}>
                <td>{paciente.name}</td>
                <td>{paciente.birth date}</td>
                <td>{paciente.cpf}</td>
                <td>{paciente.gender}</td>
                <td>{paciente.address}</td>
                <td>{paciente.status}</td>
                <td>
                  <Button className="button muted-button" onClick={() => removePaciente(index)}>
                    <i style={{ color: "red" }} className="fa-solid fa-trash fa-xl"></i>
                  </Button>
                  <Button className="button muted-button">
                    <i style={{ color: "orange" }} className="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square fa-xl"></i>
                  </Button>
                  {/* {condition === true ? <Cadastrar /> : <ListarPacientes />} */}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))
          ) : (
            <tr>
              <td colSpan={3}>Sem pacientes</td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ListPatients
```

**Result**
[image]

**Note: I'm using localStorage to store the data.**
[image]

How do I do it using a search input? Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 main parts I modified in your code

Firstly, you need to import these

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
```

After that we start the implementation

```
//initialise search value
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("")

//whenever search value gets updated, we will update patience list
  useEffect(() => {
    const newPacientes = pacientes.filter(value => value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
    setPacientes(newPacientes)
  }, [searchValue])
```

And lastly, we need to have search input field

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)} value={searchValue} placeholder="Search by name"/>
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const ListPatients = ({ pacientes, setPacientes }) => {
  //initialise search value
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("")
  
  //whenever search value gets updated, we will update patience list
  useEffect(() => {
    const newPacientes = pacientes.filter(value => value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
    setPacientes(newPacientes)
  }, [searchValue])
  
  const removePaciente = (idToDelete) => {
    const newTasks = [...pacientes];
    newTasks.splice(idToDelete, 1);
    setPacientes(newTasks);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ display:"flex", alignItems:"center", flexDirection:'column'}}>
      <h1>List</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)} value={searchValue} placeholder="Search by name"/>
      <Table style={{ border:'1'}}>
        <thead>
          <tr style={{padding:'0 1rem'}}>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birth date</th>
            <th>CPF</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Addres</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {pacientes.length > 0 ? (
            pacientes.map((paciente, index) => (
              <tr key={paciente.id}>
                <td>{paciente.name}</td>
                <td>{paciente.birth date}</td>
                <td>{paciente.cpf}</td>
                <td>{paciente.gender}</td>
                <td>{paciente.address}</td>
                <td>{paciente.status}</td>
                <td>
                  <Button className="button muted-button" onClick={() => removePaciente(index)}>
                    <i style={{ color: "red" }} className="fa-solid fa-trash fa-xl"></i>
                  </Button>
                  <Button className="button muted-button">
                    <i style={{ color: "orange" }} className="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square fa-xl"></i>
                  </Button>
                  {/* {condition === true ? <Cadastrar /> : <ListarPacientes />} */}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))
          ) : (
            <tr>
              <td colSpan={3}>Sem pacientes</td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ListPatients
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple. You will need to define the state where you will keep the `searchInput` value

```
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState()
```

Then you should create a function that will filter your patients

```
const getFilteredPatients = () => {
  if (!searchInput) return patients
  return patients.filter(patient => patient.name.toLowerCase() === searchInput.toLowerCase())
}
```

and just call it in a proper place.

Overall it should look like

```
const ListPatients = props => {
  const { patients, setPatients } = props

  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState()

  const removePatient = patientId => {
    const newPatients = patients.filter(patient => patient.id !== patientId)
    setPatients(newPatients)
  }

  const getFilteredPatients = () => {
    if (!searchInput) return patients
    return patients.filter(
      patient => patient.name.toLowerCase() === searchInput.toLowerCase()
    )
  }

  const filteredPatients = getFilteredPatients()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>List</h1>
      <Table style={{ border: '1' }}>
        <thead>
          <tr style={{ padding: '0 1rem' }}>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birth date</th>
            <th>CPF</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Addres</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {patients.length === 0 && (
            <tr>
              <td colSpan={3}>Sem pacientes</td>
            </tr>
          )}

          {filteredPatients.map(patient => (
            <tr key={patient.id}>
              <td>{patient.name}</td>
              <td>{patient.birth_date}</td>
              <td>{patient.cpf}</td>
              <td>{patient.gender}</td>
              <td>{patient.address}</td>
              <td>{patient.status}</td>
              <td>
                <Button
                  className="button muted-button"
                  onClick={() => removePatient(patient.id)}
                >
                  <i
                    style={{ color: 'red' }}
                    className="fa-solid fa-trash fa-xl"
                  />
                </Button>
                <Button className="button muted-button">
                  <i
                    style={{ color: 'orange' }}
                    className="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square fa-xl"
                  />
                </Button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ListPatients
```

Answer (score 1):

first step -

```
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("")
const [data,setData]=useState([])
```

second step -

```
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products").then((res)=>{
      const newPacientes = res.data.filter(value => value.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()))
      setData(newPacientes)
    })
  },[searchValue])
```

and add ui input -

```
  <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)} value={searchValue} placeholder="Search by name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import "./Crud.scss"
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Toaster, toast } from 'react-hot-toast'
const Crud = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("")
    const [dummys, setDummy] = useState(false)
    const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState("asc"); 


    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/robots").then((res) => {
            setData(res.data)
        })
    }, [searchValue === "", dummys])
    return (
        <div className="robots">
            <div className="robots__top">
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => {
                    setSearchValue(e.target.value)
                    setData(data.filter((item) => item.title.includes(searchValue)))


                }} />



             

                <button onClick={() => {
                    const sortedData = [...data];

                    if (sortOrder === "asc") {
                        sortedData.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
                        setSortOrder("desc");
                    } else {
                        sortedData.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
                        setSortOrder("asc");
                    }

                    setData(sortedData);
                }}>
                    Sort By Price
                </button>







                <h1>Featured Robotics Products to Show</h1>
                <p>Who are in extremely love with eco friendly system.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="robots__bottom">
                {data.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="robots__bottom__card">
                            <div className="robots__bottom__card__img">
                                <img src={item.image} alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="robots__bottom__card__content">
                                <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                                <p>{item.desc}</p>
                                <p>${item.price}</p>
                                <div className="robots__bottom__card__content__buttons">
                                    <Link to={`${item._id}`}><button>VIEW DETAILS</button></Link>
                                    <button onClick={(e) => {
                                        axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/robots/${item._id}`).then((res) => {
                                            setDummy(!dummys);
                                            toast.success("Item succesfully deleted");

                                        })
                                    }}>DELETE</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <Toaster/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Crud
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.